# Is there a better way to prevent javascript variable hoisting errors than to put script at the bottom of views in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have several javascript files in my Rails 4 app and though they seem to work fine each one has been throwing undefined variable errors(variable hoisting I assume) in the js console that accumulate quite rapidly. This only happens if I put the scripts in the assets folder and use the Asset Pipeline. If I put the scripts at the bottom of my views I don't get the errors, but this doesn't feel like the rails way to me. I'm not that experienced with js so I wonder if maybe my js code is written poorly?

A typical file looks similar to this:

```
var quals;
if($('#resource_quals').val() !== ""){
  quals = $('#resource_quals').val().split(',');
  for (var i=0; i < quals.length; i++){
    $('#quals a').filter(function(){ return $(this).text() ===  quals[i];}).toggleClass('has_qual')
  }
}

$('#quals a').click(function(event){
value = $(this).text();

$(this).toggleClass('has_qual');

if($(this).hasClass('has_qual')) {
  quals.push(value);

} else {
  for(var i = resources.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(quals[i] === value) {
      quals.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
}

$('#resource_quals').val(quals);
event.preventDefault();
});
```

I've tried various different approaches such as wrapping all the variables inside functions but nothing is working except putting the files at the bottom of the views? Any thoughts?

Comment: When you put them at the bottom of the view, do you put them in the correct order (which is different from alphabetical order of filenames)?

Comment: No, I didn't really think about order when I put them at the bottom of the page. Only that they should be there. When they were in my assets folder I tried both requiring them in the manifest file and not requiring them. Both worked but I had console errors in both cases.